# Unable to open XD file in Adobe XD. Getting Error "r.states is not iterable"

Tags: user-interface, adobe

I have one design file(.xd file). When I am trying to open that in my Adobe XD it's showing the error "r.states is not iterable" and close the XD. Please help me to solve this issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 - update adobe xd

2 - restart computer

3 - open adobe xd and log in creative cloud

4 - try again

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have already tried this. It's not working.

Comment: adobe xd team say it's a bug and it will be fixed soon. you can see here  for more information : https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd/error-while-opening-cloud-doc-quot-r-states-is-not-iterable-quot/m-p/12101966